# Backup and Restore database MDF C# WinForm didnt work

Tags: c#, winforms, backup, restore, mdf

Im trying to Backup and Restore my database .MDF file in C# WinForms. 
I think it backup because I saw a .BAK file but when I restore, its not working. Both have no error on runtime but I think theres something wrong with my code.
Here's my code:

```
    private void backupToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveFileDialogBackUp.FileName = fileName;// +".bak";
        saveFileDialogBackUp.Filter = "Backup File (*.bak)|*.bak";
        saveFileDialogBackUp.Title = "File Location";

        try
        {
            saveFileDialogBackUp.InitialDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Sauvegardes";
            if (saveFileDialogBackUp.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"BACKUP DATABASE [dbCPS] TO  DISK = '" +
            saveFileDialogBackUp.FileName + ".bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = +
            N'dbCPS-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10 ", +
            conn);
                conn.Close();
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Backup Successful!", "CPS Backup", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }                           
        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void restoreToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialogBackUp.Filter = "Backup File (*.bak)|*.bak";
        openFileDialogBackUp.FileName = "CPS";
        openFileDialogBackUp.InitialDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Sauvegardes";
        if (openFileDialogBackUp.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //RestoreDatabase(conn, "dbCPS", openFileDialogBackUp.FileName);

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GlobalVar.connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"RESTORE DATABASE dbCPS FROM DISK = '" + openFileDialogBackUp.FileName + @"' WITH RECOVERY, MOVE 'dbCPS' TO 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New backup\dbCPS.mdf', MOVE 'dbCPS_log' TO 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New backup\dbCPS_Log.ldf', REPLACE", connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    // Add the parameters for the SelectCommand.

                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Database Restored", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at using SMO library.  Should be a lot easier that scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use

```
public void BackupDatabase(String databaseName, String userName, 
        String password, String serverName, String destinationPath)
 {



 Backup sqlBackup = new Backup();

sqlBackup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
sqlBackup.BackupSetDescription = "ArchiveDataBase:" + 
                                 DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
sqlBackup.BackupSetName = "Archive";

sqlBackup.Database = databaseName;

BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(destinationPath, DeviceType.File);
ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

Database db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];

sqlBackup.Initialize = true;
sqlBackup.Checksum = true;
sqlBackup.ContinueAfterError = true;

sqlBackup.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
sqlBackup.Incremental = false;

sqlBackup.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
sqlBackup.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;

sqlBackup.FormatMedia = false;

sqlBackup.SqlBackup(sqlServer);


}

public void RestoreDatabase(String databaseName, String filePath, 
       String serverName, String userName, String password, 
       String dataFilePath, String logFilePath)
{
    Restore sqlRestore = new Restore();

BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(filePath, DeviceType.File);
sqlRestore.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
sqlRestore.Database = databaseName;

ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

Database db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
sqlRestore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
String dataFileLocation = dataFilePath + databaseName + ".mdf";
String logFileLocation = logFilePath + databaseName + "_Log.ldf";
db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
RelocateFile rf = new RelocateFile(databaseName, dataFileLocation);

sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(databaseName, dataFileLocation));
sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(databaseName+"_log", logFileLocation));
sqlRestore.ReplaceDatabase = true;
sqlRestore.Complete += new ServerMessageEventHandler(sqlRestore_Complete);
sqlRestore.PercentCompleteNotification = 10;
sqlRestore.PercentComplete += 
   new PercentCompleteEventHandler(sqlRestore_PercentComplete);

sqlRestore.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
db.SetOnline();
sqlServer.Refresh();
}
```

Alternative

```
public static bool backup(string path, ref Exception _ex)
        {
            bool res = true;
            try
            {
                path_to_save = path;
                if (!Directory.Exists(path_to_save))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path_to_save);

                final_path = path_to_save + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".bak";
                Server myServer = new Server("servername");
                Backup bkpDBFull = new Backup();
                /* Specify whether you want to back up database or files or log */
                bkpDBFull.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
                Database myDatabase = myServer.Databases["yourdatabase"];
                /* Specify the name of the database to back up */
                bkpDBFull.Database = myDatabase.Name;
                /* You can take backup on several media type (disk or tape), here I am
                 * using File type and storing backup on the file system */
                bkpDBFull.Devices.AddDevice(final_path, DeviceType.File);


                bkpDBFull.BackupSetName = "yourdatabase database Backup";
                bkpDBFull.BackupSetDescription = "yourdatabase database - Full Backup";
                /* You can specify the expiration date for your backup data
                 * after that date backup data would not be relevant */
                bkpDBFull.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10);

                /* You can specify Initialize = false (default) to create a new
                 * backup set which will be appended as last backup set on the media. You
                 * can specify Initialize = true to make the backup as first set on the
                 * medium and to overwrite any other existing backup sets if the all the
                 * backup sets have expired and specified backup set name matches with
                 * the name on the medium */
                bkpDBFull.Initialize = false;

                /* Wiring up events for progress monitoring */
                bkpDBFull.PercentComplete += CompletionStatusInPercent;
                bkpDBFull.Complete += Backup_Completed;

                /* SqlBackup method starts to take back up
                 * You can also use SqlBackupAsync method to perform the backup
                 * operation asynchronously */
                bkpDBFull.SqlBackup(myServer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { res = false; _ex = ex; }
            return res;
        }
```

Comment: i tried to use your code but im having an error using the BackupDatabase method.

`BackupDatabase("MyDatabase.mdf", "C:\\");`

and error prompts in
`sqlBackup.SqlBackup(sqlServer)`
**FailedOperationExeception was unhandled**
Backup failed for Server 'My-PC\SQLExpress.'

Comment: My connection is on windows authentication mode. Or do you mean rights on drive C? My user is on Administrator access. Can you provide some example on how to use exactly the method? Thank.